# Error with Event ID: 2002 and Source: EapHost

Tags: events, windows-7, registry, viewer

I constantly receive in Event Viewer an Error at every reboot:

Skipping: Eap method DLL path name validation failed. Error: typeId=21, authorId=29114, vendorId=0, vendorType=0

Source: EapHost
Event ID: 2002
Level: Error
User: System
Task Category: Peer
Keywords: Registry

Someone have any idea?

Comment: No idea, but I get these all the time too.

Comment: Getting bit with this. Seems to be a SecureW2 error.